# how can I remove the index property in array that the array has only the numbers without key prop?

Tags: javascript

I have a array like this:

```
let arr = [
   {
     index: 1,
     price: "24.99"
   },
   {
     index: 2,
     price: "24.95"
   },
   {
     index: 3,
     price: "20.95"
   },
]
```

I want only the prices now in the array like this:

```
let arr = ["24.99", "24.95", "20.95"]
```

How I make this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a perfect opportunity for `map`

`arr = arr.map((el) => el.price)`

Gives

`[ "24.99", "24.95", "20.95" ]`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Array.map` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const objarr = [{
    index: 1,
    price: "24.99"
  },
  {
    index: 2,
    price: "24.95"
  },
  {
    index: 3,
    price: "20.95"
  },
]

const arr = objarr.map((element) => element.price);
console.log(arr);
```